# How can I refactor this code to return the frequency of numbers instead of frequency of characters?

Tags: python, char, numbers, coursera-api

I saw this Python code to show frequency of characters and I would like it to return frequency of strings but I am unable to do it right

```
def count_letters(text):
    import string
    result = {}
    
    # Go through each letter in the text
    
    for int in text:
    
        # Check if the letter needs to be counted or not
        if letter in string.ascii_letters:
          letter = letter.lower()
          if letter not in result:
            result[letter] = 0
        # Add or increment the value in the dictionary
          result[letter] += 1
    
    return result
```

print(count_numbers("This is a sentence."))
#Should be {}

print(count_numbers("55 North Center Drive"))
#Should be {'5': 2}

Comment: `if letter.isdigit():`?

Comment: Are you looking to count the frequency of individual digits (from 0 to 9) or would you process consecutive digits in the string as distinct numbers ?  Also, please format your code properly so it all appears in the grey box.  A sample input and expected output would also help us help you.

Comment: Yes. I'm looking to count the frequency of the individual digits. I will add the sample I/O now

Comment: Please, remove your refactoring tag. You want to change the functionality of your code, that is not [refactor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring).

Comment: Change `for int in text:` to `for letter in text` and `if letter in string.ascii_letters` to `if letter in string.digits`.   You also don't need the .lower() conversion.

Comment: Thank you Alain T. That should fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Counter class from the collections modules.  A Counter() is a special kind of dictionary that counts instances of the keys you give it.  You can use the filter function to extract only the digits out of the text.

```
from collections import Counter

text =  "55 North Center Drive"
result = Counter(filter(str.isdigit,text)) 
print(result)

Counter({'5': 2})
```

If you don't want to use a library, you can do the same thing with a normal dictionary:

```
result = dict()
result.update( (d,result.get(d,0)+1) for d in filter(str.isdigit,text) )
```